# Interface and crash problems on low-end tablets

Tags: android

I'm currently designing a digital menu application for Android tablets.

Here's how we are currently working: each restaurant receives a number of Android devices with our application installed (mostly 7 inches tablets) - they are low-end devices of various unknown and weird brands. They are all 4.0+, though.

We tried our best to optimize the interface based on a 7" 1024x600 testing device, using dp and sp units. Unfortunately, there are a lot of models that behave differently from this one despite the fact that they have exactly the same physical size and resolution! Actually, I did not find any device to behave the same as another... how is this possible?

Another great issue is instability. Even after exhausted testing on some models (some low-end, some high-end - such as Samsung's latest models) showing no exceptions or errors at all, we find some tablets randomly crashing with no apparent reason - same setup, same app, different tablets. Many times it is impossible to know what caused the crash, since it won't happen on a developing environment and there's no log; also, reproducing the steps that led into the crash won't result on any problem whatsoever.

My question is: are those problems sitting on the low-end tablets manufacturers' hands or is this somehow related to the way we are developing? Are those issues manageable at all?

Comment: It could be either one. Try integrating a crash-reporting tool(ACRA, Crittercism, etc) to your app. At least that way you'll get meaningful feedback when it does crash.

Comment: there is also the Android version to consider. Even though resolutions, size and pixel density may all be the same, the OS may be the differing factor.  We have 4 tablets on our team and all 4 have different OS : 4.0.3, 4.1.2, 4.2.2 and 4.3

Comment: Also, if you connect a tablet that has recently crashed to Logcat, you have a few minutes in which to catch the output of any exceptions.

Comment: There are also a handful of free apps that let you view logcat output directly on the device.